# Rational Software Architect: UML to Java transformation: Java Source Code Layout

Tags: java, eclipse, rational-rsa

I am using IBM Rational Software Architect for creating a UML Model and then transforming it to Java Code.
Unfortunately the generated Java Souce Code format isn't the greatest, at least it is not the format I want to use. An example:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package net.game3.shared.entity;

/** 
 * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
 * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
 * @author Heinrich
 * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
 */
public class Structure {
    /** 
     * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
     * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
     * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
     */
    private String type;

    /** 
     * @return the type
     * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
     */
    public String getType() {
        // begin-user-code
        return type;
        // end-user-code
    }

    /** 
     * @param type the type to set
     * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        // begin-user-code
        this.type = type;
        // end-user-code
    }

    /** 
     * <!-- begin-UML-doc -->
     * <!-- end-UML-doc -->
     * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
     */
    private Integer id;

    /** 
     * @return the id
     * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        // begin-user-code
        return id;
        // end-user-code
    }

    /** 
     * @param id the id to set
     * @generated "UML to Java (com.ibm.xtools.transform.uml2.java5.internal.UML2JavaTransform)"
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        // begin-user-code
        this.id = id;
        // end-user-code
    }
}
```

One point is, I would like to see all private member variables to be declared first and then the getter/setter methods follow.

Both RSA and Eclipse are very powerful tools why I hope that someone of you knows a way to change or specify the Source Code Layout/Format.

Best Regards,
Erik

Comment: Interested in an answer for this question. Upvoted.

Comment: What don't you like?  The cluttering javadoc comments?  Or just the positioning of the private members?  This is one of the reasons why I don't like IBM products.  You do it their way or no way.  Sorry I'm not more helpful - I don't have to use Rational, thank god.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions`. One of the "additional actions" is "Sort members". It'll reorganize the class members (like privates fields being grouped) after each save. Might also want to look into the `Java > Code Style > Formatter` to see if it helps.

**Edit**: If you're not going to edit the files and still want to Sort Members, you can do it via the Project Explorer context menu under `Source > Sort Members...`.

Every time I've used generated code, I had to massage it a bit anyway and assumed you would too. My bad.

Comment: Okay, that is a good option for me! Even if I think that this is still a little hack because we are not really going to change the Java File Transformation.
Maybe it can be solved creating a custom transformer or something like this?